# Não selecionar registros que tenham o campo status='Desligado'

Tags: php, mysql, query, mysqli

```
$query = "SELECT uf , count(*) as number FROM tab_clientes GROUP BY uf ";
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente porém tenho no banco um campo status que classifica a pessoa como Desligado (precisa continuar cadastrado para outros relatórios).

Gostaria que os registros não entrassem na consulta acima quando o campo `status='Desligado'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só usar um `where`

```
$query = "SELECT uf , count(*) as number " .
         "FROM tab_clientes " .
         "WHERE status <> 'Desligado'" .
         "GROUP BY uf ";
```